# Append to text file in MIPS one character at a time?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a loop that is printing to the console one character at a time. I want to write these characters to a text file instead, but the problem is that the text file is being overwritten each time I'm writing to it. This means that only a single character is in the text file by the time the loop is done.

I have seen lots of mentions online of writing to a file character by character, but no explanation of how this can be done. Maybe a buffer can be used to solve this? I have not been able to find any clear example using buffers either, so I'm not sure if this is the case or how it would work.

Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty easy to do, so if you're doing it wrong, then show us the code that's going wrong, and maybe we can help.

Comment: Sounds like you are reopening the file inside the loop.

Comment: Is this with MARS toy system calls?  (As opposed to GNU/Linux MIPS, for example in a qemu emulator, where the open() system call can take an `O_APPEND` flag.)  Oh actually, according to the MARS system calls docs (http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html), open does have a write-with-append flag value, vs. write-only with create (and truncate I guess).  So even if you do want to inefficiently open/close for every character, you can still append.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I stupidly was opening the file in the loop. That fixed that one problem and of course there's lots more now lol. Made a new post with the full code, didn't want you to think I didn't see your comments. @ErikEidt